# What is disableSelection used for in jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can someone help me understand why is this useful and when to use it?

```
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

It's useful if you want to make text unselectable. If, for instance, you want to make drag-and-drop elements with text on, it'd be annoying to the user if the text on the box accidentally would get selected when trying to drag the box.

Comment: I agree!  So, why did they deprecate disableSelection()?

Comment: @ScottStafford Because generally disabling selection is bad for the UI experience. With jQuery, selection is still automatically disabled when using [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/). Also, the same effect can now be achieved using CSS: `user-select: none`. See [this article about user-select on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fuser-select).

Answer (score 8):

Caveat emptor: `.disableSelection()` is actually harmful on some browsers, as it prevents clicking active elements (e.g. `textarea`s) inside the sortable.

- Firefox 33.1 for Mac OS X (Yosemite): `.disableSelection()` prevents clicking on embedded `textarea`; doesn't seem to have any effect otherwise (i.e. it is still impossible to select text with the mouse in the sortable if omitted)
- Chrome 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit) for Mac OS X: `.disableSelection()` seems to have no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery documentation says to not use it http://api.jqueryui.com/disableselection/

Also, I found that it made elements with `contenteditable="true"` no longer editable.