# jQuery UI sortable 'cancel' option doesn't work in FF

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox

I have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hSnc/12/) showing the problem. If you open this one in FF 32.0.1 (the latest as of now), you'll notice that the `<select>` is not clickable. Chrome works awesome.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Briefly for those not willing to open the link:

html:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li><span>drag me 1
        <select>
            <option value="somevalue1">some value 1</option>
            <option value="somevalue2">some value 2</option>
        </select>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li><span>drag me 2</span></li>
    <li><span>drag me 3</span></li>
    <li><span>drag me 4</span></li>
</ul>
```

js (using [cancel](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel) docs):

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    handle: "span",
    cancel: "select"
}).disableSelection();
```

css:

```
span {
    cursor: move;
}
#sortable {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#sortable li {
    margin: 3px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: I would put the `select` tag outside the `span` tag. But this change does not fix your problem...

Comment: @cor yep, I would do that, too, but I have to deal with such markup, at least for now. And yes - that does not fix the problem, which is a pity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by the disableSelection()

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426795/what-is-disableselection-used-for-in-jquery-sortable) and see if you can remove disableSelection, it seems it's by default now. Try the fiddle without the disableSelection()

Comment: unbelievable, how simple it turned out to be!